# What does this translate to? - The game #1

Tags: pattern, language

[image: Text]

The above picture translates to:

`"[speaking to you] Welcome. This puzzle is one [or 'the first'] of many that you will solve [or 'that will be solved by you']. I will not give you the solution to this puzzle; (or ',') you will have to work with others to solve it. [end of section]"`

A few notes: (which I will place in a spoiler block in case you want to go into this completely blind)

> The empty circle at the beginning (the large one with the two lines coming out is the same thing as the slightly deformed looking circle at the end. The U shape and the two squares inside of it are the same as the U shape and the two squares that are in the crossed off box. The open line and the double line are both intentional.

Given that, what does:

[image: Text]

translate to?

This is (I think) quite difficult, so feel free to ask for hints and collaborate with each other.

Hints (new one each unsolved day, with a max of 5):
#1

> The two squares stacked on top of each other means "puzzle"

#2

> The vertical line (|) that spans from top to bottom means "." (period) The double line means "end of section (paragraph, statement, etc)" The line with a break in the middle means "," (comma) and the line that goes inward, then sideways, then outward, and then continues is ":" (colen)

#3

> (in most cases) putting a line through something means that it is completed

#4

> putting a U shape under something means "this"

#5

> A straight horizontal line with a dot in the middle specifies the tense, behind the dot is past tense, on it is present, and past it is future

Give me a good partial answer and I will give you the bounty, so long as no full answers come in.

Edit:

Here is recreation of the first drawing with straighter lines:

[image: Text]

Comment: Can I request better drawings? This penmanship is *atrocious* ;-)

Comment: @tuskiomi sorry, I drew these with a keyboard and mouse, and my  fine motor skills are not that great anyway. I will try to recreate this with straighter lines.

Comment: @RewanDemontay This is my puzzle, I will try to make the puzzle more legible.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Thanks :). I added a more readable version below in case you are interested.

Comment: @MilesZew I'm being facetious. They're fine!

Comment: @tuskiomi I probably should have anyways. It's very hard if you can't tell if one thing is the same as another :)

Comment: New hint when?​

Comment: @u_ndefined because I added a bounty I won't be giving hints until it is up, but seeing as nobody's solved it in seven days I will add one more

Answer (score 2):

**Partial / Attempt :**

I must start by admitting that what I have found so far is almost surely a *very vague* answer (if it can be considered such), and *by no means* a complete one.

First, I want to clarify what I understood about each figure from the question. Some of these are already mentioned by the OP, still :

> [image]

And

> [image]

Thus, the text from question, in more *literal* sense is:

> You are welcome. This puzzle is one of many similar things which will be solved. I am not solving this puzzle for you. You work with others to solve this puzzle.

Now, some of these symbols are present in the answer, some are not. Here is my thought:

> [image]

Unfortunately, this is it. I know it is very incoherent, but I could not find anything more, neither could I understand any other way of interpreting the images.

Comment: Regarding your solution to the puzzle: (part one) rot13(Lbhe vagrecergngvba bs "guvf chmmyrf gbc unys" vf irel pybfr gb jung vg zrnaf ohg abg dhvgr. Gur "lbh" naq "V/Zr" jrer pbeerpg. Gur "lbh ner fbyivat sbe zr" jnf abg pbeerpg, gur pvepyr vafvqr gur pvepyr vf qrprcgvir. Lbhe "gbc cneg abg fbyirq" vagrecergngvba vf jnl bss, guvf jnf cebonoyl gur uneqrfg cneg. Lbhe vagrecergngvba bs "fbyivat guvf chmmyr sbe lbh" unf fbzr ryrzragf gung ner pbeerpg.)

Comment: (part two) rot13(Abgvpr gur cerfrag grafr (juvpu abeznyyl qbrf abg arrq gb or fgngrq). Lbh unir gur evtug vqrn. Svanyyl gur pebff unf abguvat gb qb jvgu eryvtvba. Vg vf n pbzovangvba bs gjb guvatf/ehyrf. "Erq zbba" vf pbeerpg. Abgr gur pvepyr.) rot13.com

Comment: Regarding your interpretation of the original answer. rot13(Lbh tbg rirelguvat pbeerpg rkprcg sbe n srj guvatf. Lbhe vagrecergngvba bs "Fvzvyne guvatf" vf bss onfr, vg eryngrf gb "bar." Lbhe "jbex jvgu bguref" onfvpnyyl pbeerpg ohg abg dhvgr. Lbhe vagrecergngvba bs "fbyir" vf jnl bss onfr, vg unf gb qb jvgu "jbex.")

Comment: all in all, pretty good answer. If nobody else comes up with a better/correct answer (or an answer that doesn't rely on your answer too much) then I will give you the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough feedback :) @MilesZew

Answer (score 0):

Building on the above answer:

> I feel like the last Blood Moon part must be something like:
>
>  Then the bounty points are awarded to the accepted answerer.

But it's a guess.

Comment: Not quite on track. @SamRoy Remember that putting a line through something normally means complete, which can sometimes mean "at capacity" or "full" or something like that.

Comment: @SamRoy. Also remember that circle often means "you"